# How can I highlight a list of strings on a web page using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text file with a bunch of unformatted lines of text:

```
this is string 1
this is string 2 with multiple ch$r$t#rs and in-text citations[1]
this is string 3
```

...

I need to use these strings as inputs for a JS function that highlights each occurrence of the strings on a web page. Ideally, there would be a way pass the text file to the function.

What functions/code are the most suitable for achieving this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "highlight" plugin for jQuery that allows any input you like..

```
$.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
    function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                spannode.className = 'highlight';
                var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                skip = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
            }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    return this.each(function()
        {
            innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
        }
    );
};
$.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
    return this.find("span.highlight").each(function()
        {
            this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
            with (this.parentNode) {
                replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
                normalize();
            }
        }
    ).end();
};
```

and it's usage:

```
$('body').highlight(needle);
```

My CSS (but you can set your own):

```
.highlight {background-color:yellow;color:black;}
```

Comment: All you do is add the entire plugin code to your custom JS file (or create a `plugins.jquery.js` file and include it. The CSS goes in an external style sheet or in the head section of the page.

Comment: OK. It works with simple phrases, but anything with symbols doesn't get highlighted. Also, how can I pass multiple strings at once?

Comment: Be sure to use HTMLentities for any symbols so it can be decoded properly. For instance, `Georger&Weasey` would be `George&amp;Weasey`. With multiple strings, you'd have to modify the code to convert the new line characters to `\n`.

Comment: I tried to encode the strings, but while a string like "perhaps empty" gets highlighted, a "(perhaps empty),[4]" doesn't. It seems like parentheses and brackets don't get escaped. :(

Comment: I think it might actually be the comma trying to input the `needle` as an array. You'll have to play around with the code (convert everything to a string before testing for an occurrence). Sorry, I only use it for simple text.